# Issues with Telegram Bot Deployment using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I'm trying to deploy a bot using an app script (from Google). I have a problem with the doPost function. It forwards messages from the user, but does not send a welcome message on the start command, nor does it send a notification that the message has been sent. Also, the problem is that it does not send a link to the user's account, but only his ID. When trying to run the doPost function in the editor, an error appears
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postData')
doPost @ Code.gs:20 . I would be very grateful if you could help me figure it out.

```
const TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "-----------------------------";
const ADMIN_CHAT_ID = "----------"; 

const WEB_APP_URL = "-------------------------------------------------------";

function setWebhook() {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/setWebhook?url=${WEB_APP_URL}`, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Telegram Bot is active.");
}

function doPost(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const updateId = data.update_id;
  const message = data.message;
  const chatId = message.chat.id;
  const text = message.text;

  if (text === "/start") {
    sendTelegramMessage(chatId, "Hello!");
  } else {
    sendTelegramMessage(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, `new massagefrom user Chat ID: ${chatId}\n\nСообщение: ${text}\n\nTelegram-acc of user: https://t.me/${data.message.from.username}`);
    sendTelegramMessage(chatId, "massage was send to admin");
  }
}


function sendTelegramMessage(chatId, text) {
  const payload = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: chatId,
      text: text,
    },
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage`, payload);
}
function sendMessageToUser(chatId, text) {
  const payload = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: chatId,
      text: text,
    },
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendMessage`, payload);
}
```

did several checks on the advice of gpt chat, received the following errors 23:28:55 Information Received request:
23:28:55 Information Invalid request data. 'method' property not found in the request.
the method itself with checks -

```
function doPost(e) {
   try {
     Logger.log("Received request:", e);

     if (e && e.postData && e.postData.contents) {
       const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
       logger.log("Received data:", data);

       if (data.message) {
         const chatId = data.message.chat.id;
         const text = data.message.text;
         Logger.log("Received message:", text);

         if (text === "/start") {
           sendTelegramMessage(chatId, "Hello! You have pressed /start. Nice to see you!");
         } else {
           sendTelegramMessage(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, `New message from user with Chat ID: ${chatId}\n\nMessage: ${text}`);
           sendMessageToUser(chatId, "Your message was successfully sent to the administration.");
         }
       } else {
         Logger.log("No 'message' field in the received data.");
       }
     } else {
       Logger.log("Invalid request data. 'method' property not found in the request.");
     }
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
}
```

p.s. TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN , ADMIN_CHAT_ID and WEB_APP_URL have been checked many times for correctness